# Language Grammar History

Tags: language

I was trying to search for an article on the Web but cannot find from an authentic source.

I want to know when and which language was first formalized and its grammar specified.

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by "formalized" and in what form the grammar is specified, i.e. are you after the first language where the rules of the language were written down (rather than passed on orally)?

Comment: i would say more written down

Comment: Related question on Language Learning.SE : http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/what-are-some-of-the-oldest-documented-language-learning-techniques-or-resources

Comment: Also seems like it might be more OT on the Linguistics SE site.

Answer (score 6):

The oldest known linguistic description is a Sanskrit grammar by Pāṇini, from maybe 5th century BCE. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%87ini) has a good summary.